# How to add textview to dynamic surfaceview android

Tags: android, textview, surfaceview

Actually my problem is I want to add text view to surface view at a particular position whether it may be corner or centre.In this I am getting surface view dynamically and I have to add text view to this surface view dynamically please help me

Comment: you can use `sufaceview.addView(textview,layoutparams)`.

Comment: so what is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to write the text directly into the SurfaceView. To do this, you can create your custom implementation of SurfaceView by extending it. Then, rewrite the onDraw() method to draw your text on top of it.

Haven't tested to see if this works, but trye something like:

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView {

    Paint paint;

    public MySurfaceView() {

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(25);

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public class onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawText("Your Text", 10, 10, paint);
    }

}
```